# Вопрос безопасности PHP. Как пользователю удалось внести изменения в функцию mail()?

Tags: php, безопасность

Есть сайт, на нем каждый день регистрируются пользователи, разумеется встречаются и роботы, которые создают спам-статьи на форуме с рекламой определенных продуктов.

Создал защиту от роботов, путем обязательной верификации указанного email. Больше спам на сайт не лезет, однако недавно один робот меня удивил.

Когда новый пользователь проходит регистрацию, ему на почту летит письмо с одноразовым кодом, а мне (админу) высылается письмо тоже при помощи стандартной функции mail()

```
function new_registration($to,$s,$body)
{
    $from_name="********";
    $from_a = "admin@*******";
    $reply="admin@*******";
    $s= "=?utf-8?b?".base64_encode($s)."?=";
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers.= "From: =?utf-8?b?".base64_encode($from_name)."?= <".$from_a.">\r\n";
    $headers.= "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $headers.= "Reply-To: $reply\r\n";  
    $headers.= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
    mail($to, $s, $body, $headers);
}
```

Вызывается эта функция:

```
new_registration("******@gmail.com", "Новый пользователь!", "Логин: " . $login . "\nСтрана - " . $country . "\nЗарегался в " . $date_registr . "\nПочта: " . $email);
```

и на почту обычно получаю письмо вида:

- Логин: ********
- Страна - Казахстан
- Зарегался в 06.12.2020
- Почта: **********@mail.ru

Все отлично. Однако получил я письмо вот какое:

- 袥芯谐懈薪: Michaeladext
- 小褌褉邪薪邪 - 项朦
- 袟邪褉械谐邪谢褋褟 胁 06.12.2020
- 袩芯褔褌邪: ahmedkirillov5@gmail.com

Вопрос, как это возможно? Как ему удалось заменить заданные мною текстовые значения на свои?Дайте совет!

ЗЫ. Логин и электронка в общедоступных БД спамеров

Comment: http://phpfaq.ru/tech/mail

Comment: @Ипатьев не совсем то, нет проблемы с загаловками, есть подмена прописаных мною в скрипте частей кода. Эти краказябры не результат сбившейся кодировки, а результат подмены. Приглядитесь

Comment: new_registration вы сами используете для уведомлений о новых пользователях. Данные которые пришли к вам намекают что что-то произошло до её вызова так как ваша кодировака поменялась. Рекомендую вставить код до неё на который у вас есть подозрения.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov в том то и прикол, кодировка не менялась. ф-ция new_registration() содержит три параметра, (кому, тема, содержимое) вот в строке кода (не в переменной) и произошло изменение.

Answer (score 0):

У вас в письме просто сбилась кодировка (как правильно отметили в комментариях). Заходите на http://www.online-decoder.com/ru , вставляете эти ваши кракозябры:

```
袥芯谐懈薪: Michaeladext
小褌褉邪薪邪 - 项朦
袟邪褉械谐邪谢褋褟 胁 06.12.2020
袩芯褔褌邪:
```

и выбираете `Раскодировать текст автоматически (рекомендуется): Подбор`. Получаете свои:

```
Логин: Michaeladext
Страна -���� �
Зарегался в 06.12.2020
Почта: a
```

Comment: в программировании ничего не происходит просто так, всему что то предшествует. Я Вижу, что что то сбилось и инетресно разобраться что предшествовало этому. На моем сайте постоянно кто то регистрируется, но именно этот спам-бот сбил кодировку, вопрос - как именно!

Comment: При заполнении полей формы регистрации вставлял символы в своей кодировке. У него "раскладка клавиатуры" другая, как у китайца - что ни нажми будет печататься кракозябра, если в операционке нет поддержки иероглифов..

Comment: Тогда еще вопрос, там где написано "Страна" - ответ что в переводе, что в "оригинале" -  кракозябры, хотят у пользователя нет возможности вписать туда что либо, там значение подставляется из <select> ! Как тогда он это сделал? Хотите я дам вам ссылку на сайт, вы сами попробуете)

Comment: Косяк со страной объяснить не могу. Возможно, это бот-спамер и он не выбирал селектом из списка, а послал своё поле с этим именем. Но у этого посетителя была выбрана раскладка клавиатуры, отличная от русского языка. В UTF8 65565 разных символов, и он просто присылал коды символов в другой раскладке. Забейте, вас не взломали!

Comment: меня так просто не взломать)) У меня везде по две проверки) Просто было любопытно) Вы кстати не знаете кого то, кто мог бы сайт на уязвимости протестировать?

Comment: Не, не знаю. И я бы не стал доверять незнакомому "спецу" со фриланса и тп - може он и есть "хакер". Пусти такого "козла в огород", он обнаружит уязвимости и будет их использовать. Я держу бэкап движка сайта и регулярно делаю бэкапы БД. Можно поставить WatchDog - скрипт, который периодически проверяет контрольные суммы (CRC) и даты изменения файлов движка сайта.